# Powermock createPartialMockForAllMethodsExcept throwing null pointer because field is null?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mocking, powermock

I'm using powermock like so:

```
  DetailServiceImpl impl=PowerMock.createPartialMockForAllMethodsExcept(
DetailServiceImpl.class, "getServiceDetail", JSONObject.class,String.class);

Whitebox.invokeMethod(impl,"getServiceDetail",response,dateFormat.format(date).toString());
```

However, when this line is run, "getServiceDetail" is executed and a null pointer exception is thrown because the method being mocked on the class DetailServiceImpl uses a class field that is autowired by spring, but on this mock it is null.

By the time I've made this assignment to the variable impl, the method is already run so I can't just do:

impl.setField(myFieldObjMock);

because it's already too late.

How can I fix this issue so that I can either set this field before the method is ran, or have powermock not leave this field null?

____Edit: added WhiteBox call in test in code example_____

Comment: Which version of PowerMock or EasyMock are you using? This is a bit weird as I just tried your example with latest version of both libraries and worked well. On the other hand this just creates a mock object and it should not be called unless you explicitly call after creation

Comment: It's powermock 1.4 and easymock 3.2. When that line get's called in debugger, it jumps to execution of that method "getServiceDetail", and since all fields of DetailServiceImpl are null, when it steps over the line that uses one of the fields it throws a null pointer. Also should be stated that the next line of code uses WhiteBox. Please see edit above.

Comment: What's odd is that I enter execution of the method not when I step over the Whitebox.invoke() method, but when createPartialMockForAllMethodsExcept gets executed.

Comment: I used version `1.4.6` of `powermock-module-junit4`, `1.4.6` of `powermock-api-easymock`, `3.2` of `easymock` and `junit` version `4.12`. But I was not able to reproduce this behavior.